# Possibility of a canonical Fn-invert question?

Tags: discussion, canonical-answer

[Annoying Fn keys](https://superuser.com/questions/605114/annoying-fn-keys)

[How To Permanently Lock the "Fn" Key Down So It Is Active On My Laptop Keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/235796/how-to-permanently-lock-the-fn-key-down-so-it-is-active-on-my-laptop-keyboard)

[How can I make my laptop F-key's work as F-keys?](https://superuser.com/questions/590417/how-can-i-make-my-laptop-f-keys-work-as-f-keys?lq=1)

[F-Keys are Alternate by default on a Gateway Toshiba Laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/337170/f-keys-are-alternate-by-default-on-a-gateway-toshiba-laptop?rq=1)

[HP laptop F1-12 keys inverted with Fn](https://superuser.com/questions/279809/hp-laptop-f1-12-keys-inverted-with-fn?lq=1)

[How do I use the function keys on Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/650672/how-do-i-use-the-function-keys-on-windows-8?lq=1)

and possibly countless others.

Could someone make a canonical CW question with instructions on restoring the function keys back to how God intended them to work for various laptop makes?